# Centering a dynamically sized div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

Not being a web guy I don't know all the quirks of HTML.  I am attempting to center some dynamically sized content inside of a div.  This content should always be centered, so I hooked into `window.resize` to do it.  I then manually call `window.resize()` after applying the CSS to force it to run once.

The problem is that the div does not center horizontally *at first*, only vertically.  Subsequent window resizes force the div to center properly.

Initially I thought that I must be trying to center the div before it was 'ready' as I am calling it first *before* `document.ready` fires, but the vertical centering works and I added some trace statements and, sure enough, the `left` position is being calculated correctly, just not applied (seemingly).

Anyway, this is my first real foray into HTML+CSS, so I'm sure you guys will nail it quickly.  Here is some sample html and javascript which reproduces the problem.

Also, my testing has been in Chrome exclusively thus far.

```
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>         
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            $(function() {
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    var win = $(window);
                    var area = $('#signuparea');
                    $('#signuparea').css({
                        position: 'absolute',                       
                        left: (win.width() - area.outerWidth()) / 2,
                        top: (win.height() - area.outerHeight()) / 2
                    });

                    //$('body').append('<div>l=' + ((win.width() - area.outerWidth()) / 2) + '</div>');                     
                    //$('body').append('<div>w=' + area.outerWidth() + '</div>');
                    //$('body').append('<div>h=' + area.outerHeight() + '</div>');
                });

                $(window).resize();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:0000FF">
            <div id="signuparea">           
                <input type="password">
            </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that area.outerWidth() returns too big value initially, and therefore signuparea isn't correctly positioned. This is corrected when user resizes the window but not before. https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/97 suggests that outerWidth has actually innerWidth of parent element.

Comment: @MetalRain: Thanks for looking into it, but if you uncomment the trace statements you will notice that the calculated value is initially correct, the div simply doesn't center vertically. Also, that page notes that upgrading to JQuery 1.5 fixes the problem and I am using 1.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using this code in your `window.resize` event handler:

```
$('#signuparea').css({
    position      : 'absolute',                       
    left          : '50%',
    top           : '50%',
    'margin-top'  : '-' + Math.round(area.height() / 2) + 'px',
    'margin-left' : '-' + Math.round(area.width() / 2) + 'px'
});
```

Since three of the properties set above are static they can be set in CSS:

```
#signuparea {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 50%;
    left     : 50%;
}
```

Which makes your JS look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var area = $('#signuparea');
        $('#signuparea').css({
            'margin-top'  : '-' + Math.round(area.height() / 2) + 'px',   
            'margin-left' : '-' + Math.round(area.width() / 2) + 'px',       
        });
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Ty6Af/2/

Comment: Same thing unfortunately; the first page load only centers the div vertically, subsequent resizes act center in both directions.  I could just say screw it and define a width for the div, but now I want to know why this isn't working reliably so that I know what to do (and what not to do) in the future.

Comment: @EdS. If you check-out the jsfiddle you'll see it working on `document.ready` and on `window.resize`.

Comment: @EdS. If your code works but not on the initial page-load then it seems like the `$(window).resize();` code is not firing the `resize` event on `document.ready`.

Comment: And we have a winner.  Now I'm going to play around and find out why moving a couple things into a static style worked whereas the first did not.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, so if I use your example and pull `position:absolute` out of the static style and into the resize function it fails.  This seems to be the problem, now I need to figure out why before I move on.  Thanks again.

Comment: @EdS. You cannot set the position of an element to `absolute` and set its margin at the same time, apparently. Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle where I make two `.css()` calls, one to change the position of the element and one to change its margin: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Ty6Af/5/

Comment: Well that is... interesting.  Thanks again Jasper.

Comment: @Scott I answered EdS.'s other question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274554/applying-positionabsolute-to-a-style-via-jquery-fails-to-center-div-horizontall/8274630#8274630

Answer (score 0):

If you give your `div` a width then `margin: 0 auto` centers it (zero can be replaced with whatever for top and bottom margin, it is the left/right margin that needs `auto`.

Sorry, missed that it was `absolute`. That requires `left: 50%` with a `margin-left: -??` where ?? is half the width of your div.

Comment: So I am trying to center the div without knowing what the width will be.  I realize that, with a known width, this can be done purely in CSS, but can't it be done reliably without knowing the width?  It works after resizing the window manually (and always works in the vertical), just not when the page first loads.  That's the part I don't understand.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, one more thing; I also realize that a div will expand to fill all available width, but when I inspect it in the test script it is only as wide as the text area.  And again, it works after resizing the window.  I'm boggled, this is why I stay away from UI work :)