# Applying position:absolute to a style via jQuery fails to center div horizontally upon first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

This is a followup to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274008/centering-a-dynamically-sized-div/8274115#8274115). I would like to understand why applying `position:absolute` to the CSS of a div via jQuery fails, while applying it in a static style works.  Here are two jsfiddle examples:

Works: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Ty6Af/2/

No worky: http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6Af/3/

Note that the only difference between the two is where I apply `position:absolute`.  Vertical centering always works, but horizontal centering does not work when the page loads for the first time.  If you manually re-size the window the div will center correctly.

All of my testing has been on Chrome under Ubuntu thus far.

Anyway, I'm just now delving into the world of web development and these are exactly the kinds of 'quirks' that I need to begin understanding.

EDIT:

@Jasper found something interesting.  If you make two calls to `.css()`, first applying `position` and subsequently applying a margin, it works.  I would love to understand why.  Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Ty6Af/5/

Comment: they look the same to me what browser are you using?

Comment: @Adam: Sorry, Chrome on ubuntu.  So they both center right away for you eh?

Comment: yes in FF on windows, the trigger method is having problems with chrome for jquery currently so you have to run the function to make it position absolute on load too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is with how the width of the div is calculated by the browser depending on its `position`.

- If the div is set to `position : static` (by default) then it's width is 100% of it's parents width and the element is not allowed to move around the page.
- If the div is set to `position : relative` then it's width is 100% of it's parents width but it can be moved around with `left`.
- If the div is set to `position : absolute` then its width is determined by the actual content of the div, for instance if there is only a `200px` wide `<span>` element within the div then the div will be `200px` wide.

You can test these observations by changing the CSS of your jsfiddle to specify `position : relative` (etc...) and remove the JavaScript that makes the div `position : absolute`, then use your Developer Tools to inspect the element and it's calculated width.

The problem with your code is that it sets the `position : absolute` at the same time it sets the `margin` of the element by using its width/height (which are calculated differently depending on the `position` of the element).

If you want to set the `position` of the div in JavaScript then you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {

    //notice I cached the selector so it can be used in the future as well as set the position of the div
    $signuparea = $('#signuparea').css({position : 'absolute'});
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $signuparea.css({
            'margin-top'  : '-' + Math.round($signuparea.height() / 2) + 'px',   
            'margin-left' : '-' + Math.round($signuparea.width() / 2) + 'px',       
        });
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Ty6Af/8/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that when you apply your left and right in your second fiddle, you have yet to add position absolute to the div. Hence, the browser has no idea what do with the left and right values and ignores them initially.

Practically speaking in your second fiddle, you only actually add the position:absolute on the resize trigger. So before you resize your actual div has no positioning.

If you instead add the position absolute on load it works fine:http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6Af/9/

Notice that if you give it position:relative from the start (like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6Af/11/ ) it allready applies both the left and right value. The reason you can't actually see the effect of "left" is because it is a block element.

I hope that answers your question, I'm not quite clear on where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6Af/7/ this should work, the trigger function in jquery has bugs with chrome so you have to run the function on load too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `position:absolute;` negates the current layout and requires you to position it.....

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHaRD/

Which Jasper explains much more eloquently than myself!